# It's ok to mix Conda install and Pip install?

Tags: python, pip, conda

I find `conda install` faster (something like numpy)

however I have to sometimes do `pip install` to get versions that's not available in conda.

Is it safe to mix them inside conda environment?

So I did,

```
conda activate my-venv
conda install pip
conda install foo
pip install bar
```

Comment: On Windows, more than a year ago, I noticed that `pip install` did not mix well, particularly when trying to export a `requirements` file of the virtualenv. Every package installed through `pip` for any virtualenv were listed in the requirements, the only way at the time was to update this file manually... Not sure if it has evolved in between though

Comment: More information can be found https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Situation improves starting with [conda `4.6`](https://www.anaconda.com/conda-4-6-release/) and the `pip_interop_enabled` feature. So in the future it should be safe.

For now the recommendations stated in the [comment of @Christoffer](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/) should remain true.

Note that it you encounter Pypi packages not available in conda, and if it is appropriate, you can create a recipe and submit to open-source community-managed channels [`conda-forge`](https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/adding_pkgs.html) or [`bioconda`](https://bioconda.github.io/contribute-a-recipe.html). This way you won't have to ask "pip or conda?" anymore.